# Switching the Sort filter Parameter in Java 8 Comparator's Sort method

Tags: java, java-8, comparator

How to change the sort parameter based on a null check in Java 8 stream.

Example:

`myList = myList .stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Profile::getFirstName)).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Here if getFirstName turns out NULL, I want to use another value getLastName.

Like:

```
if(Profile.getFirstName()==null)

Sort using Profile.getLastName()

else

Sort using Profile.getFirstName()
```

Comment: Dont use a method reference, but a lambda instead?

Comment: Unless it is a hard requirement to replace the list with a new list, you can just call `sort(comparator)` on the list, by the way.

Answer (score 3):

```
...sorted(Comparator.comparing(x -> x.getFirstName() == null ? x.getLastName() : x.getFirstName()))....
```

Comment: this will not compile because **Comparator** functional interface takes two argument.

Answer (score 1):

I did this:

```
 myList = myList.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(profile->profile.getFirstName()==null? profile.getLastName():profile.getFirstName())).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    myList.stream().sorted((a, b) -> {
        if(a.getFirstName() != null && b.getFirstName() != null) {
            return a.getFirstName().compareTo(b.getFirstName());
        }

        if (a.getLastName() != null && b.getLastName() != null) {
            return a.getLastName().compareTo(b.getLastName());
        }

        return 0;
    });
```